# What are the differences of implementations in Neo4j and Memgrpah?

Tags: memgraphdb

I couldn't find `FOREACH` defined in OpenCypher, but I found it in Neo4j and Memgraph implementations of Cypher query language. Does anyone know what is the difference between this two implementations?